# Mentioning bot breaks all other commands

Tags: discord.py

I noticed that if you make a event like this:

-

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if client.user.mentioned_in(message):
        await message.channel.send("Hmmm?")
```

It would break all your client.commands, not allowing you to use your prefix.
Any help with going over this?

Answer (score 0):

If you override `on_message`, you will have to add a line to tell the bot to process the commands. You  can do this by using the `client.process_commands` coroutine.

So your `on_message` function can be written as:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if client.user.mentioned_in(message):
        await message.channel.send("Hmmm?")

    await client.process_commands(message)
```